# Should Tags [react-router-dom] and [react-router] be combined?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process

[`react-router`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router) and [`react-router-dom`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-dom) are two separate npm packages where one extends the other.  `react-router` contains the base logic while `react-router-dom` bind this logic to the web and is the package that is actually used in a typical React project.  There is also the [`react-router-native`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-native) package for React Native which is rarely used and has 32k weekly downloads compared to 4.2 million for `react-router-dom`.  Both versions are simply called "React Router" in their [docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start).

What is the best way to deal with the associated tags on Stack Overflow?

- [react-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-router) 15,402 questions
- [react-router-dom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-router-dom) 3,375  questions
- [1,555 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-router+react-router-dom) tagged with both
- [react-router-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-router-native) 31 questions

Though technically different, the [react-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-router) and [react-router-dom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-router-dom) are essentially used as synonyms.  Virtually every question on [react-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-router) has to do with the web package rather than the native one.  I would like some canonicalization here.

Comment: Leave it. The React Native package isn't as popular, but it's still it's own thing and it may get more popular over time.

Comment: @Jared one option would be to keep react-router-dom and react-router-native as the two tags and redirect react-router to react-router-dom.

Comment: I could image that to lead to questions getting tagged as react-router-dom and react-router-native at the same time because people would tag them as react-router (because clearly that is part of it, with react-router-native inheriting from it) and react-router-native.

Comment: be careful with the synonym, there are questions tagged with [both `[react-native]` and `[react-router]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-native+react-router) they should probably be first retagged to `[react-native] [react-native-router]`

Comment: @Lino Thanks for the link.  It actually highlights quite a lot of mistags which need to be manually fixed!  Many are web codes which should not have the [react-native] tag.  Others are about [react-navigation] which is a totally separate package from [react-router].

Comment: Good question. I will typically add `react-router-dom`|`react-router-native` to these questions as it is the more specific tag, and leave the more general `react-router` since it has more widespread visibility. I totally agree when used together like this they are basically synonymous and redundant. Very rarely have I come across a core-specific `react-router`-only question. I'm honestly a bit more concerned about more easily identifying the `react-router-dom` versions as there are many breaking changes between v5 and v6, though this may be an entirely different conversation.

Comment: I've gone through about 5 pages of the posts linked by @Lino with both [tag:react-native] and [tag:react-router].  There are a handful that warrant both tags but 90-95% are mistagged and need one (occasionally both) of those tags removed.  There is another bad pairing [react-router and react-navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-navigation+react-router) with 104 questions.  These are two separate libraries that would never be used in the same project so unless the user is asking about the differences between them then one of the tags is a mistake.

Comment: Another tag to add to the cleanup: [tag:react-routing] has 59 questions, most of which should be tagged with react-router instead.  Though there are [a few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61975437/isomorphic-routing-with-react-nginx-not-working-with-proxy) that genuinely have nothing to do with the react-router package.